# function querying all elements from mongodb does not populate array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, foreach

so i've written a function that *should* query everything in the `files` inventory of my mongodb using mongoose, but instead... doesn't. while each element is in fact being read, `files.push()` doesn't seem to have any effect on the array, as the array is still empty.

while i know that `console.log()` is not an effective way to debug, considering express still does not render the contents of the array, it is in fact not being populated.

yes, it is being called as `getAllFiles(Image)`.

code below:

```
const Image = module.exports = mongoose.model('files', imageSchema);

function getAllFiles(collection) {
  let files = [];

  collection.find({}, (err, buns) => {    
    buns.forEach((bun) => {
      let fin = bun.path.replace("public/", "");
      files.push(fin);
      console.log(fin);
    });
  });

  console.log(files);
  return files;
}
```

terminal output (ignore extraneous outputs):

```
wildflower :: src/bunnydb » node app.js
(node:23296) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.running on port 3000
[]
uploads/9160d961-3d9b-4dea-a39c-f79b86647408.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to fix by adding a callback as it was running asynchronously:

```
function getAllFiles(collection, cb) {
  let files = [];

  collection.find({}, (err, buns) => {    
    console.log('err: ' + err);
    console.log('buns: ' + buns);
    buns.forEach((bun) => {
      let fin = bun.path.replace("public/", "");
      files.push(fin);
      console.log('data: ' + fin);
    });
    cb(files);
  });

  console.log('arr: ' + files);
  return files;
}
```

and on invocation the callback argument can be used to do stuff with the files